# How to adjust column height of a web page when variable data is obtained through ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I am working on an asp.net website which has a master page and is ajax enabled. The master page has three column architecture with three divs. After the page loads, I use java script to find the tallest of the three columns and set the height of all three columns to this value, which pushes down the footer appropriately. This works fine during the page load. In some of the pages I have dropdown boxes, which when used to select values, gets different data through the update panel (ajax). When the data rows obtained are too big, the central column goes beyond the footer and the java script doesn't fire to reset the column height. Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried handling this on window.onresize?

Comment: Yes, I tried. But, the onresize() event is not fired at the end of ajax execution.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved the issue as follows:

1. Added the following code to the page_load function on the code behind of the page which had the updatepanel

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "resize", "AdjustColumnsHeight();", true);

1. The master page had the AdjustColumnsHeight() js function which reset the height of the coulmns based upon the new height.